# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de enviar dato Ajax a controlador C#?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Soy nuevo en asp.net, tengo el siguiente código que me añade datos a la vista pero quiero enviarlo al controlador para después guardarlo en la base de datos

**Codigo js**

```
$(".agregarCate").click(function () {

    if ($("#custom_textbox").val() != "") {
        var deleteButton = "<button class='delete btn btn-warning'>Borrar</button>";
        var editButton = "<button class='edit btn btn-success'>Editar</button>";
        var twoButtons = "<div class='btn-group pull-right'>" + deleteButton + editButton + "</div>";
        $(".list_of_items").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + "<div class='text_holder'>" + $("#custom_textbox").val() + twoButtons + "</div><br/></li>");
        $("#custom_textbox").val('');

        $.ajax({
            url: "~/Controllers/CategoriaController/cate_Dato",
            method: "POST",
            data: { data: $("#custom_textbox").val() },
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta2) {
                console.log("Respuesta", respuesta2);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Codigo del controlador**

```
public string cate_Dato(string cate)
        {
            string data=cate;
            return cate;
        }
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de enviar el dato de JS, al método `cate_Dato`.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En ASP.NET MVC no se especifica el nombre del archivo/clase completo para poder acceder a ellos, sino que se especifica el nombre del controlador ignorando la palabra *controller* y el nombre del metodo(llamado action en mvc) al que deseas navegar/enviar datos.

En tu caso estas especificando una ruta absoluta del archivo:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "~/Controllers/CategoriaController/cate_Dato",
```

Cuando deberia de ser:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "~/Categoria/cate_Dato",
//..
```

Nota como se ignoro la palabra `Controller`, esto no es necesario especificarlo. Si tienes un controllador llamado `VisitasController`, solo necesitas poner `~/visitas/` y listo. tambien se ignoro el nombre del folder que es *Controllers*, esto porque MVC ya sabe que en la carpeta *Controllers* estan los controladores(En realidad lo sabe porque la clase `CategoriaController` hereda de [`System.Web.Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx) pero para mantener las cosas simples me reservo solo a decir eso).

Tambien los parametros que envias desde ajax tienen que tener los mismos nombres especificados en el metodo/action al que deseas enviarlo. Cuando haces esto:

```
$.ajax({
          //..
            data: { data: $("#custom_textbox").val() },
          //..
```

MVC espera que el metodo `cate_Dato` tenga un parametro llamado `data`, pero en tu caso se llama `cate` por lo que debería de ser así:

```
$.ajax({
   //..
   data: { cate : $("#custom_textbox").val() },
  //..
```

Y por ultimo el en el ajax estas especificando que sera un `POST`. Para que MVC reconozca ese tipo de método http, tienes que especificarlo con el atributo `[HttPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public string cate_Dato(string cate)
//...
```

Asi MVC sabra que es un post y obtendra los parametros del cuerpo de la peticion. Los tipos mas utizados son `[HttpPost]` y `[HttpGet]` que se utiliza cuando es un `GET`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo una duda, ¿Por que no puedo mostrar el `success: function (respuesta2) {
                console.log("Respuesta", respuesta2);

            }` Si estoy devolviendo el valor, para mostrarlo en la consola? Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Recibes un dato tipo JSON y devuelves una string

```
public string cate_Dato(string cate)
        {
            string data=cate;
            return cate;
        }
```

Deberías probar con:

```
public JsonResult cate_Dato(string cate)
        {
            string data=cate;
            return cate;
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.